# Get element from which onclick function is called

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button with a onclick attribute which is pointing to the function `test()`.

```
<button onclick="test()">Button 1</button>
<button onclick="test()">Button 2</button>
<button onclick="test()">Button 3</button>
```

Function test():

```
function test()
{
    var button_name = this.html;
    console.log("Im button "+ button_name);
}
```

How can I get informations about the clicked button?
e.g. How can i read the html?

**jsfiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/c2sc9j9e/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Pass the `this` reference to the function, then read [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) property the text content of the node.

*HTML*

```
<button onclick="test(this)">Button 1</button>
```

*Script*

```
function test(clickedElement){
   var button_name = clickedElement.textContent;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c2sc9j9e/2/)

Answer (score 5):

I came across an other extremely simple way to do it in Vanilla JS so I post it here for reference:

```js
function whoami () {
  var caller = event.target;
  alert("I'm " + caller.textContent);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="whoami()">Button 1</button>
<button onclick="whoami()">Button 2</button>
<button onclick="whoami()">Button 3</button>
```

I'm not sure about the browser support for it but it works at least on Safari, Firefox and Blink based browsers.

Comment: Excellent! And you don't even need the variable, if you just need it 1 or 2 times: `alert(event.target.textContent)` is enough. Would be nice to know since when this direct solution is supported.

Comment: This has been around since the dawn of time (well, at least since Safari 1.1 which was released in 2003). Its deprecated though and may be removed at some point, so you probably shouldn't use it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event

Answer (score 4):

Four options:

1. Pass `this` into the function.

   ```
   <button onclick="test(this)">Button 1</button>
   ```

   and then use that argument in the function.
2. Hook up the handlers with `addEventListener` or jQuery's `on`, and then use `this` within the handler.

   ```
   var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("selector-for-the-buttons");
   Array.prototype.forEach.call(buttons, function(btn) {
       btn.addEventListener("click", handler, false);
   });
   function handler() {
       // Use `this` here
   }
   ```

   jQuery version:

   ```
   $("selector-for-the-buttons").on("click", function() {
       // Use `this` here
   });
   ```
3. Hook up a single handler on a container these buttons are in, and use the `target` property of the event object to determine which was clicked (but note that if you use other elements within `button`, you'll need to loop up to the `button` first).

   ```
   document.querySelector("selector-for-the-container").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
       // Use `e.target` here
   }, false);
   ```

   jQuery version that handles the possibility of nested elements within the `button` for you:

   ```
   $("selector-for-the-container").on("click", "button", function() {
       // Use `this` here (note this is different from the DOM version above)
   });
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```js
 function test(button)
 {
     var button_name = button.getAttribute('name');
     console.log("Im button "+ button_name);
 }
```

```html
 <button onclick="test(this)" name="button1">Button 1</button>
 <button onclick="test(this)" name="button2">Button 2</button>
 <button onclick="test(this)" name="button3">Button 3</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Jquery, then you can call the $(this) object in the function.

Answer (score 1):

you must pass "this" to function

```
<button onclick="test(this)">1</button>
<button onclick="test(this)">2</button>
<button onclick="test(this)">3</button>

<script>
    function test(t)
    {
        console.log(t);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ionutmihai1995/c2sc9j9e/3/) , using jquery.

```
<button onclick="test(this)">1</button>
<button onclick="test(this)">2</button>
<button onclick="test(this)">3</button>

<script>
   function test(button)
   {
       var button_name = $(button).html();
       alert("Im button "+ button_name);
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the event that triggers the click, and you do that by specifying the function call as MyFunction(event).  For example:

```
<ul>
 <li onclick="MyFunction(event)">Red</li>
 <li onclick="MyFunction(event)">Orange</li>
 <li onclick="MyFunction(event)">Yellow</li>
</ul>
```

and then your Javascript function can be:

```
function MyFunction(ev) {
  // Now you have access to everything in the event
  //- including the triggering element

  var element = ev.srcElement;

}
```

By leaving out the (event) parameter in the specification of the onclick function call you don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

just add id to each button and pass it to your test function

and here is **[working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/matheen821/6pd5nj0r/1/)**

```
<button onclick="test(this.id)" id="button1">1</button>
<button onclick="test(this.id)" id="button2">2</button>
<button onclick="test(this.id)" id="button3">3</button>

<script>
    function test(id)
    {
        var button_name = id;
        alert("Im button name is : "+ button_name);
        console.log("Im button name is :"+ button_name);
    }
</script>
```