# Array from filter click

Tags: javascript

I have a list of elements, I want to get on click only the one that I clicked on.I tried to do it this way

```js
const menuItems = document.querySelectorAll(".Account-navigation-item-link");

menuItems.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let its = Array.from(menuItems)
      .filter((i) => i.click)
console.log(its)




  });
});
```

```html
  <ul class="Account-navigation">
   
  <a
        href="#"
        class="Account-navigation-item-link Account-navigation-item-link-active"
        >Мои данные</a
      >
  <a
        href="#"
        class="Account-navigation-item-link"
        >Схемы лечения</a
      >
   
   
      <a
        href="/logout"
        class="Account-navigation-item-link"
        >Выйти</a
   
  </ul>
```

**But now I get all elements**

[image]

Comment: `i.click` will be a function. Why is this the filter condition?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Because I want to get a list of items and filter it on which clicked

Comment: `event.currentTarget` will get you the element that is clicked on

Comment: Because all of them indeed have (`click`), it's the native browser callback of clicking. If you want to get the item whose clicked use `item.addEventListener("click", e => e.target)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get element from which onclick function is called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40234130/get-element-from-which-onclick-function-is-called)

Comment: You could have a custom attribute `data-clicked` that you set to `true` when the element is clicked; in this way it should be easy to keep track and filter all the menu items that were clicked. The limit is that if you refresh the page you will lose that information, unless you save it somewhere. A simple example (without information persistence) is here: https://jsfiddle.net/xomrb40L/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) or [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) to get the element that is clicked. The difference is that `event.currentTarget` will always return the element which we have bound the click event listener to, while `event.target` may refer to descendants inside the clicked element.

In your case, since the `<a>` tags have no descendants, `event.target` or `event.currentTarget` will always yield the same element, and it shouldn't matter which one you use.

```js
const menuItems = document.querySelectorAll(".Account-navigation-item-link");

menuItems.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    console.log(e.currentTarget);
  });
});
```

```html
<ul class="Account-navigation">
   
  <a
        href="#"
        class="Account-navigation-item-link Account-navigation-item-link-active"
        >Мои данные</a
      >
  <a
        href="#"
        class="Account-navigation-item-link"
        >Схемы лечения</a
      >
   
   
      <a
        href="/logout"
        class="Account-navigation-item-link"
        >Выйти</a
   
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const menuItems = document.querySelectorAll(".Account-navigation-item-link");
menuItems.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", () => {  
      let its = Array.from(menuItems).filter(function(e) {
            return event.currentTarget == e;
      })
      console.log(its);
    
  });
});
```

You should try this.

Comment: The`isClick` variable seems superfluous, as you never use it.

Comment: Yes, i forgot to remove this line so i edit this.

Comment: Furthermore: (1) `event.currentTarget` cannot be equal to the event in the same way a limb cannot be equal to a person and (2) if all you need is the element you are currently clicking on, that would already be `event.currentTarget`, there is no point in looping through all menu items to filter the element.